# Manifest v3 Proxy Authentication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

With the new manifest v3 came the doom of `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking`, how are we suppose to authenticate a proxy request?

Old way:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
    callbackFn({
        authCredentials: { username: username, password: password }
    });
},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},['asyncBlocking']);
```

So my question besides the one above is what is the new way of doing this? Docs say that `webRequest` is replaced by `declarativeNetRequest`, but they don't provide one single example of how to do this.
Manifest v3 looks like is broken and google developers don't care anymore:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135492.

Comment: Don't use ManifstV3 until https://crbug.com/1135492 is fixed.

Comment: @wOxxOm Following talks about `webRequestAuthProvider` and it appears to have been pushed (also noted on above bug) (I dont know which version will it appear in) https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/extensions-reviews/c/WEtDeiGxbuM

Comment: It's in 108. To find the version, enter r-prefixed rev number (r1054834) in ["Find releases" here](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/).

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't have found it. It is easier on bugzilla.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in your `manifest.json` the `webRequestAuthProvider` permission.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Chrome Auth Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestAuthProvider"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version": "22.0.0"
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the solution for Manifest v3. Setting `host_permissions` is also required. At least in my testing, `webRequestAuthProvider` works with `"blocking"` but not `"asyncBlocking"`